# b-table items for deeply nested arrays

Tags: vue.js, multidimensional-array, bootstrap-vue, v-model

I have a `b-table` and within that b-table I use `row.details` to display some more information. In fact, the details are a sub-array of the overall array. Within the row.details I want to use another b-table to display all details.
Eventually, I'll change some values of the subarray. To do so, I have to know the `index` of the `current row` that I look at in `row.details`.
So this is my question: for my second b-table, how can I set the items this way, that I still have the row path from my initial b-table?

I was thinking of writing some function to store the row I'm currently in in a global variable and find that index in my second b-table items and continue the path then.
But I was also wondering there might be an easier solution and to "hand over" the path from the initial b-table.

**My data look like this:**

```
rooms:
[
    {
        room0: "firstroom",
        details: [
            {detail0: ""},
            {detail1: [
                {subDetail0: ""},
                {subDetail1: ""}
            ]}
        ]
    },
    {
        room1: "secondroom",
        details: [
            {detail0: ""},
            {detail1: [
                {subDetail0: ""},
                {subDetail1: ""}
            ]}
        ]
    },
],
subDetailsHeader:
[
    {key: "details"},
    ...
]
```

**And that's the structure of the bootstrap-vue html(using same items for both tables - which "kills" the path of the first table)**

```
<b-table :items="rooms" :fields="roomsHeader" head-variant="light">
    <template #cell(actions)="row" >
        <button @click="row.toggleDetails()">Details</button>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:cell(selected)="row" >
        <b-table :items="rooms" :fields"subDetailsHeader">
            <template #cell(date)="row">
                {{ row.items }}
            </template>
        </b-table>
    </template>
</b-table>
```

`{{ row.items }}` now displays the details of all rooms whereas I only want do display the details of the selected room (that's why I say "killing the room path").
Actually, I'll have the same problem when I add the `subDetails` following the same (nested) scheme. Help or recommendations are highly appreciated since I'm quite new to programming :) thanks in advance!

**// Edit 1:**

The overall problem can be solved by using `slots` instead of `items` for the second- and third-level `b-table`

However, I still have problems displaying an `array/object` in the second-level `b-table`

Here's a data example:

```
rooms:
[    
    {
        "room": "HS004",
        "maxcapacity": 200,
        "selected": true,
        "period": {
            "2021-05-10": [
                {"slot_one": 200},
                {"slot_two": 200},
                {"slot_three": 200},
                {"slot_four": 200},
                {"slot_five": 200},
                {"slot_six": 200}
            ],
            "2021-05-11": [
                {"slot_one": 200},
                {"slot_two": 200},
                {"slot_three": 200},
                {"slot_four": 200},
                {"slot_five": 200},
                {"slot_six": 200}
            ],
            "2021-05-12": [
                {"slot_one": 200},
                {"slot_two": 200},
                {"slot_three": 200},
                {"slot_four": 200},
                {"slot_five": 200},
                {"slot_six": 200}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "room": "HS006",
        "maxcapacity": 200,
        "selected": true,
        "period": {
            "2021-05-10": [
                {"slot_one": 150},
                {"slot_two": 150},
                {"slot_three": 150},
                {"slot_four": 150},
                {"slot_five": 150},
                {"slot_six": 150}
            ],
            "2021-05-11": [
                {"slot_one": 200},
                {"slot_two": 200},
                {"slot_three": 200},
                {"slot_four": 0},
                {"slot_five": 0},
                {"slot_six": 0}
            ],
            "2021-05-12": [
                {"slot_one": 150},
                {"slot_two": 150},
                {"slot_three": 150},
                {"slot_four": 150},
                {"slot_five": 150},
                {"slot_six": 150}
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

my goal is, to display the `objectNames` of each `row.item.period` as a table and by clicking one date, open another detail section / modal where I can edit the six slots of this room/period pair. In order to store it with v-model, I need the whole path `room.period.slot`

Perhaps I'm missing another way. I could also display it as a `list`, but then I don't know how to assign the slot' of the selected list-item into the overall v-model

My initial post listed all periods of each room inthe second b-table. However, I only wanted to have the period of the selected room.

**// Edit 2:**
I followed the idea from Iman and replaced my second `b-table` by a `custom table`. Now I can apply the v-model and assign the data correctly within my multidimensional array:

```
<b-table :items="roomTest" :fields="roomsHeader" head-variant="light">
  <template #cell(actions)="row">
      <b-button @click="row.toggleDetails()">Details</b-button>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:row-details="row">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Datum</th>
          <th>08:00</th>
          <th>10:00</th>
          <th>12:00</th>
          <th>14:00</th>
          <th>16:00</th>
          <th>18:00</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(value, key) in row.item.period" :key="key">
          <td>
            {{ key }}
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" v-model="Object.values(value[0])"></td>
          <td><input type="text" v-model="Object.values(value[1])"></td>
          <td><input type="text" v-model="Object.values(value[2])"></td>
          <td><input type="text" v-model="Object.values(value[3])"></td>
          <td><input type="text" v-model="Object.values(value[4])"></td>
          <td><input type="text" v-model="Object.values(value[5])"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to implement a 3 layer `b-table` with a `toggle` button in each row. You should take a quick look at [row-details-support](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#row-details-support)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      roomsHeader: [
        'room', 'actions'
      ],
      subRoomsHeader: [
        'sub_room', 'feature', 'actions'
      ],
      rooms: [{
        room: "firstroom",
        details: [{
          sub_room: "sub_room_1",
          feature: "F1",
          "details": [{
            sub_room_2: "sub room 2",
            feature_2: "F2"
          }]

        }]
      }, ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDetails() {

    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="rooms" :fields="roomsHeader" head-variant="light">
    <template #cell(actions)="row">
      <b-button @click="row.toggleDetails()">Details</b-button>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:row-details="row">
      <b-table :items="row.item.details" :fields="subRoomsHeader">
        <template #cell(actions)="row">
          <b-button @click="row.toggleDetails()">Details</b-button>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:row-details="row">
          <b-table :items="row.item.details"></b-table>
        </template>
      </b-table>
    </template>
  </b-table>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't aware of just using ``slots`` instead of ``items``. However, there is one issue remaining that I can't solve: let's imagine (in your example), ``rooms.details`` is an object of dates (length can vary, depending on previous selections) where the ``objectName`` is the actual date and the ``objectValue`` is an array (that should then pop up as third-level-detail). Do you have any idea how to display the names of the ``rooms. details`` array in table column A and access the values via details in column B?

Comment: Your welcome, Could you please provide a real example? I'm not sure, but I think what you are saying can't implement with a table or better `b-table`, and we need to write a custom table; otherwise, share a real example to see what I can do.

Comment: I updated my initial post with a data example and some thoughts. Thank you so much for your support :)

Comment: I actually found a way to handle my problem. As you suggested, I just use a custom table. I'll perhaps still do some changes to have the third level (``slots`` in my data model`) in a modal for each row. Anyway, the behaviour works now as expected and I can assign a slot to its day and then to a room using the v-model. I'll update my initial post again with my solution. If you have another idea (e.g. solve it with b-table) I'm still curious :) Anyway, thanks a lot for guiding to the right path :)

Comment: Your welcome. I think your idea is good for this custom table, but I'll look for another way. Please consider accepting or upvoting if my answer helped you. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey guys, first thanks @ImanShafiei for the answer. Im looking a simple nested columns solution, 1 column with two nested columns (representing two dates) and so on. Can this solution achieve this? or do you have some other ideas? thanks!!